# Group by time and sum value foreach php

Tags: php

I have result in array like this

```
Array
(
    [2023-06-09 10:21:48] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
        )


    [2023-06-09 10:21:50] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2023-06-09 10:21:51] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2023-06-09 10:21:52] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
...
    [2023-06-09 10:22:53] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
        )
...
    [2023-06-09 10:23:54] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

But i need to group that result in another foreach and SUM values (count) so result should be

```
Array
(
    [2023-06-09 10:21] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
        )


    [2023-06-09 10:22] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2023-06-09 10:23] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

So basically i need to group result by time and minutes. This is what I need but how to sum values and group tham every minutes ?

```
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $timeFirst  = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($key)));
            $timeSecond = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i"));
            $final = ($timeSecond - $timeFirst) / 60;
            $finalArray[$final.' minutes ago']  = $value;
        }
```

Comment: Is `$array` coming from SQL? If not use the `date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($key)` as a key and increment it on each iteration, on first pass set it to 1.

Comment: Yes array coming from SQL

Comment: You could strip the seconds in SQL and `group by` that way also.

Comment: Yeah that would be easy but I use seconds in other foreach and that is problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want the result like the section **'so result should be'** or like the code you posted **"$finalArray[$final.' minutes ago']**

For the first option you can simply strip the seconds:

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $newKey = substr ($key, 0, 16);
   $finalArray[$newKey]['count'] = ($finalArray[$newKey]['count'] ?? 0) + $value['count'];
}
```

### EDIT

For your request on the past minutes, I suggest you run a further cycle, taking advantage of the fact that the rows to be processed will have decreased:

```
$veryFinalArray = [];
$now = new DateTime();

foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
    
    $diff = $now->diff (new DateTime($key));
    
    $minutesKey = $diff->days * 24 * 60 +
                  $diff->h * 60 +
                  $diff->i;
                  
    $veryFinalArray[$minutesKey] = $value;
}
```

I haven't added the *'minutes ago'* string because it's ever the same, evaluate yourself if it's needed.

Another interesting option can be adding a value to the previous array instead of using the *$veryFinalArray*:

```
$now = new DateTime();

foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
    
    $diff = $now->diff (new DateTime($key));
    
    $minutes = $diff->days * 24 * 60 +
               $diff->h * 60 +
               $diff->i;
                  
    $finalArray[$key]['elapsed_minutes'] = $minutes;
}
```

Comment: Way easier than parsing and re-formatting those dates.

Comment: That is strange got Error 500 in logs something like "Trying to access array offset on value of type int..." PHP 8.2

Comment: @user1405674 check that the first level of the array contains always a subkey *count*, you can also try like this: `$finalArray[$newKey]['count'] = ($finalArray[$newKey]['count'] ?? 0) + (is_array ($value) ? $value['count'] : $value);`

Comment: Yes that was problem now is working but how to back "minutes ago" ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach loop and the use of the [DateTime builtin class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to make the change to the time should do this nicely

```
$array = [
    '2023-06-09 10:21:48' => ['count' => 0] ,
    '2023-06-09 10:21:50' => ['count' => 1] ,
    '2023-06-09 10:21:51' => ['count' => 0] ,
    '2023-06-09 10:21:52' => ['count' => 1] ,
    '2023-06-09 10:22:53' => ['count' => 3] ,
    '2023-06-09 10:23:54' => ['count' => 1] 
];

$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    # reformat the time, removing the seconds
    $t = (new DateTime($key))->format('Y-m-d H:i');

    if ( array_key_exists( $t, $newArray ) ) {
        // already found this date/time so add count
        $newArray[$t]['count'] +=  $arr['count'];
    } else {
        $newArray[$t]['count'] =  $arr['count'];
    }

}
print_r($newArray);
```

And the results

```
Array
(
    [2023-06-09 10:21] => Array ( [count] => 2  )
    [2023-06-09 10:22] => Array ( [count] => 3 )
    [2023-06-09 10:23] => Array ( [count] => 1 )
)
```

Of course instead of using DateTime to remove the seconds like this

```
$t = (new DateTime($key))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

you could simply chop off the las 3 characters of the date and time like this

```
$t = substr($key, 0, -3);
```